# I've installed SQLite in Visual Studio 2013 using NuGet but the package never appears in References

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm running Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 on Windows 8.1. I've started a new C# project with the intent of using SQLite in it. However, I'm running into problems. In the Solution Explorer window I right clicked on my project name which looks like this:

**MyProj (Windows 8.1)**

and selected "Manage NuGet Packages". At that point I searched for "sqlite" under Online/All and installed this package:

**System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64) Version 1.0.96.0**

So far so good. I got no errors and the package shows up under my "Installed packages" section. However, when I look in the Solution Explorer under References, I don't see it.

Furthermore, when I type:

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

into my code, I get an error saying that it can't resolve it. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the Azure Mobile Services demo.

When I started working on the offline tutorial , Visual Studio showed the reference for Sqlite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) as missing.

I was able to download the library from the Visual Studio Gallery (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a) and then I was able to manually add the reference

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here was the link I needed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263243.aspx

Thanks for your help.